# Hadoop jps & format name node cause Segmentation fault

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I started up the cluster last night with little issues. After 45 minutes it went to do a log roll, and then the cluster started to throw JVM wait errors. Since then the cluster won't restart. When starting, the resource manager isn't getting started.

The server name node and data nodes are also off line.

I had two installs of hadoop 2.8 on the server, removed first one and reinstalled the second, making the adjustments to the files to get it restarted.

Error logs from when it crashed, appear to be a Java Stack over flow, and out of range, with a growing saved memory size in the logs. My expectations is that I have misconfigured memory some place. I went to deleted and reformat the name nodes and I get the same segmentation error. At this point not sure what to do.

Ubuntu-Mate 16.04, Hadoop 2.8, Spark for Hadoop 2.7, NFS, Scalia, ...

When I go to start yarn now I get the following error message

> hduser@nodeserver:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0/sbin$ sudo ./start-yarn.sh
>
> starting yarn daemons
>
> starting resourcemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.0/logs/yarn-root->resourcemanager-nodeserver.out
>
> /opt/hadoop-2.8.0/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 103:  5337 Segmentation >fault      nohup nice -n $YARN_NICENESS "$HADOOP_YARN_HOME"/bin/yarn -->config $YARN_CONF_DIR $command "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null
>
> node1: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.0/logs/yarn->root-nodemanager-node1.out
>   node3: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.0/logs/yarn->root-nodemanager-node3.out
>   node2: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.0/logs/yarn->root-nodemanager-node2.out
>   starting proxyserver, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.8.0/logs/yarn-root->proxyserver-nodeserver.out
>
> /opt/hadoop-2.8.0/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 103:  5424 Segmentation >fault      nohup nice -n $YARN_NICENESS "$HADOOP_YARN_HOME"/bin/yarn -->config $YARN_CONF_DIR $command "$@" > "$log" 2>&1 < /dev/null
>   hduser@nodeserver:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0/sbin$

Editing to add more error outputs for help

```
>hduser@nodeserver:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0/sbin$ jps
```

> Segmentation fault

and

```
>hduser@nodeserver:/opt/hadoop-2.8.0/bin$ sudo ./hdfs namenode -format
```

> Segmentation fault

logs which appear to show the Java stack went crazy and expanded from 512k to 5056k. So, how does one reset their stack?

> Heap:
>   def new generation   total 5056K, used 1300K [0x35c00000, 0x36170000, >0x4a950000)
>   eden space 4544K,  28% used [0x35c00000, 0x35d43b60, 0x36070000)
>    from space 512K,   1% used [0x360f0000, 0x360f1870, 0x36170000)
>    to   space 512K,   0% used [0x36070000, 0x36070000, 0x360f0000)
>   tenured generation   total 10944K, used 9507K [0x4a950000, 0x4b400000, >0x74400000)
>     the space 10944K,  86% used [0x4a950000, 0x4b298eb8, 0x4b299000, 0x4b400000)
>   Metaspace       used 18051K, capacity 18267K, committed 18476K, >reserved 18736K

Update 24 hours later, I have tried complete reinstall's on Java and Hadoop, and still no luck. When I try java -version I still get segmentation fault.

Appears I have a Stack Overflow, and no easy fix. Easier to start over and rebuild the cluster with clean software.